# Error Creating Excel File

Tags: vb.net, excel

Im using vb.net in creating excel file but it gives me an error that it cant open file because the file format or file extension file is not valid.

```
    Dim excelLocation As String = txtLocate.Text + txtFilename.Text.Trim + ".xlsx"
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim APP As New Excel.Application
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook


    If System.IO.File.Exists(excelLocation) = False Then
        System.IO.File.Create(excelLocation).Dispose()
    End If


    workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(excelLocation)
    worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim columnsCount As Integer = dgvList.Columns.Count
    For Each column In dgvList.Columns
        worksheet.Cells(1, column.Index + 1).Value = column.Name
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvList.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
        Do Until columnIndex = columnsCount
            worksheet.Cells(i + 2, columnIndex + 1).Value = dgvList.Item(columnIndex, i).Value.ToString
            columnIndex += 1
        Loop
    Next
    workbook.SaveAs()
    workbook.Close()
    MsgBox("Save!")
```

Comment: I believe your looking for the `.Save` method.

Comment: You also should be using the `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` to dispose of the excel objects.

Comment: how can i implement that to my code? @OneFineDay

Comment: The `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` goes at the end after you call `App.Quit` for each excel object worksheet, workbook, then APP.